# Problemas com modal Bootstrap e exclusão de registros

Tags: ajax, modal

Possuo uma página com n registros e, para cada um deles, há o seu respectivo botão de Delete. Ao pressioná-lo, uma modal bootstrap é aberta perguntando se confirma ou não a ação. Ao confirmar, uma função ajax é disparada, apagando o registro em questão.

Um problema apareceu quando eu fui fazer o seguinte teste: Fui clicando no comando apagar de alguns registros, porém, não confirmava. Na sequência, confirmei a exclusão de um deles. Com isso, foi deletado este último e todos os demais anteriores que eu tinha cancelado a ação. Segue abaixo o meu código:

Botão apagar:

```
<a class="delete" id="<?php echo $codigo;?>">APAGAR</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$('a.delete').click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var data = 'id=' + id ;

        $('#confirm-delete').modal('show'); 
        $("#confirm-delete").modal().find(".btn-ok").on("click", function(){
        $('#confirm-delete').modal('hide'); 

         $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "<?php echo BASEURL;?>deletar.php",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
                        $('#confirm-delete2').modal('show');
                         $("#confirm-delete2").modal().find(".confirmado").on("click", function(){
                         $('.botao-form').attr("disabled", true);                                
                         $('.botao-form').html("Aguarde...");
                            window.location.reload();                           
                         });
                   }
             });                

          });
    });
```

Página deletar.php

```
$id  = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? anti_sql_injection($_POST['id']) : 0; ;   
if ((!preg_match("([0-9])", $id))) $id = 0;
$delete1 = mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE FROM hoteis where hot_codigo='$id'"
```

Botão confirm-delete:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
            SISTEMA
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Confirma a exclusão deste estabelecimento? Esta ação não poderá ser desfeita.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Deletar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Botão confirm-delete2:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
            SISTEMA
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Estabelecimento excluído com sucesso!
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success confirmado" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pelo que entendi, é como se cada modal que eu cancelo a ação, permanecesse oculta e a partir do momento que eu confirmo o botão de uma delas, todas as anteriores são disparadas.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Eu deveria criar uma função jquery para tratar as modals que eu chamo, porém cancelo a ação (não confirmando a exclusao)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece, por que apesar de "esconder" o modal, você está fazendo o `bind` do evento de exclusão no botão de confirmar cada vez que clica em um link de excluir, como o botão permanece no `DOM`, o evento também continua atrelado a ele, por isso você deve fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$('a.delete').click(function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var data = 'id=' + id ;

    $('#confirm-delete').modal('show'); 
    $("#confirm-delete").modal().find(".btn-ok").unbind('click');
    $("#confirm-delete").modal().find(".btn-ok").on("click", function(){
    $('#confirm-delete').modal('hide'); 

     $.ajax(
        {
               type: "POST",
               url: "<?php echo BASEURL;?>deletar.php",
               data: data,
               cache: false,

               success: function()
               {
                    $('#confirm-delete2').modal('show');
                     $("#confirm-delete2").modal().find(".confirmado").on("click", function(){
                     $('.botao-form').attr("disabled", true);                                
                     $('.botao-form').html("Aguarde...");
                        window.location.reload();                           
                     });
               }
         });                

      });
});
```

No caso eu apenas adicionei a seguinte linha:

```
$("#confirm-delete").modal().find(".btn-ok").unbind('click');
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente... Obrigado a todos!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Que bom Luis, considere marcar a resposta como correta para que outras pessoas também tenham esta referência! =)

Answer (score 1):

Estás a adicionar uma acção ao botão do modal sempre que clicas no botão de apagar. O botão do modal é sempre o mesmo por isso só precisas de um event listener.

Comment: Como eu devo fazer isso Astrocrack?

Comment: Ve a resposta do Kenny Rafael que está mais completa!