# Confirmar exclusão em modal (HTML+Ajax+PHP)

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tenho um programa aqui que faz o controle de uma lista de afazeres que ficam gravados e são lidos através do banco de dados (SQL). A página principal contém uma tabela e em cada linha um botão excluir para cada entrada da tabela... Não manjo muito de Ajax mas queria usar um modal pra confirmar a exclusão (*form* envia 2 variáveis a outra página que realiza as operações do banco: a primeira é o *id* da entrada que será excluída; e a outra seria o *tipo de operação*, no caso, exclusão).

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz aí de como fazer isso.

Modal que é chamado quando clico no botão "excluir":

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Excluir Item</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">Deseja realmente excluir este item? </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok">Sim</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">N&atilde;o</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Botão "excluir registro":

```
    <td class="actions"> 
                        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' id='deleta' alt='Excluir' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal"
                name='opbanco' value='excluir' title="Excluir"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ></span></button>
 </td>
```

O `input` fica dentro de um *form* que envia os dados (`codigo(id)` e `opbanco(operacao a ser realizada)`).
 Edit:
Tentei como o @GuilhermeNascimento sugeriu "var data = 'id=' + id + '&operacao=opbanco';" e nao rola, acredito que não fui claro na minha duvida, vou complementar o codigo

" name='cod_prdc'>

Esse é o campo do form que armazena o id da linha, e clicando no botão de exclusao ele envia para outra pagina (banco.php) os 2 parâmetros através da referencia name dos campos o outro parametro 'opbanco' fica no botão excluir

Comment: Isso ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159788/3635 ?

Comment: Então cara eu vi esse artigo, mas nesse caso ele envia apenas o id por POST para a outra pagina, queria saber uma forma de enviar os 2 parâmetros de uma vez só ao confirmar a exclusao (o id e o tipo de operacao(que seria o name="opbanco" do botao excluir))

Comment: Yago é só ajustar isso: `var data = 'id=' + id ;` para algo **semelhante** a isto `var data = 'id=' + id + '&operacao=opbanco';`

Comment: Esse post indicado pelo @GuilhermeNascimento tem a solução para o seu problema, basta adicionar a operação excluir.

Comment: Editei mais uma vez o arquivo, ainda não consegui galera...gerando o modal direto pelo html ele até aparece mas o evento que deveria ocorrer quando clico em "Sim" não acontece nd...mas sem a instrução ajax